# Pasar argumentos a ejecutable.exe c#

Tags: c#, consola, clickonce

He creado una aplicacion en c# muy simple.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de argumentos: {0}", args.Length);
    foreach (string argumento in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Argumentos: {0}", argumento);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Al depurar funciona bien ya que he *seteado* los parámetros en las propiedades del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al publicar genera un setup.exe y al ejecutarlo (`setup.exe arg1 arg2`) me da el siguiente error!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añadido!

Esta es una aplicacion de tipo consola, al publicar se generan los sigueintes archivos: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de la carpeta se guardan las versiones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar setup.exe se lanza la aplicación pero no recibe los argumentos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta aplicacion la necesito ejecutar con arguento desde la consola de windows para ejecutarla con un .bat y este ponerlo en una tarea programada.**

Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: La pregunta es, porque haces un deploy que vas a llamar por línea de comandos, si necesitas acceder al ejecutable de la consola bastaría con instalarla manualmente con algo parecido a XCOPY. Si la vas a llevar a un webserver es otra historia y te puedo ayudar a resolverlo.

Comment: @Cristian La aplicación supongo que se instala offline ? es así?

Comment: ¡Hola, amigo! Tal vez ya no valga mi respuesta pero el error del index es por que el array no tiene indicado donde comenzar o en su defecto estas pasando el desborde

Answer (score 4):

El tema es que e setup.exe es el instalador de la aplicacion y no la aplicacion en si misma

Cuando publicas estas creando un instalador de ClickOnce para poder redistribuir tu desarrollo, deberias ejecutar el setup.exe, instalar la aplicacion en la pc del usuario y luego ejecutar la aplicacion con los argumentos

[Cómo: Publicar una aplicación ClickOnce sin usar el Asistente para publicación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/31kztyey.aspx)

Si te diriges a las propiedades del proyecto seguramente veas una solapa como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es alli donde configuras las opciones que generan el instalador que al compilar/publicar generaran el setup.exe, pero repito este es el instalador no la aplicacion.

Answer (score 1):

puedes obtener los argumentos de la siguiente forma

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

foreach(string arg in args){
// tu codigo
}
```

Pero debes tener en cuenta que [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx) devuelve un array con el nombre del ejecutable y el resto de argumentos, o sea, que en tu caso tendrás 3 elementos.

Answer (score -1):

Setup es el archivo de distribución, **NO es el ejecutable**. Si tu código funciona y tu proyecto se llama “parametros“ (solo por poner un ejemplo), selecciona Compilar y Compilar Parametros, Esto va a generar un EXE, que regularmente se encuentra en la carpeta parametros/BIN/Debug.

y lo ejecutas desde la consola de comandos.

> c:\Users\cristian\documents\ejecutable>parametros.exe miparametro

o bien

> c:\Users\cristian\documents\ejecutable>parametros miparametro

Comment: ¿En qué se diferenciaría esto a las respuesta publicadas hace 2 meses?